# browser gem is not detecting iPad Pro webview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using [browser gem](https://github.com/fnando/browser)'s `browser.platform.ios_webview?` method to detect requests coming from iOS webviews.

It seems to work fine except for the iPad Pro. For iPad Pro this method returns `false` instead of `true`.

Any idea why this might be happening

Rails v5.2
browser gem v4.0

Comment: I still run into this issue. Did you find a solution?